# How can I modify mnist.py file in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently doing some experiment for my research. And I want to change the labeling of the MNIST data --- to have number 0 labeled as 1, and all the other numbers labeled as -1.

I found in the mnist.py file how the labels are extracted.

```
def extract_labels(f, one_hot=False, num_classes=10 ,zero=True):
    print('Extracting', f.name)
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) as bytestream:
        magic = _read32(bytestream)
        if magic != 2049:
            raise ValueError('Invalid magic number %d in MNIST 
                                    label file: %s' % (magic, f.name))

    num_items = _read32(bytestream)
    buf = bytestream.read(num_items)
    labels = numpy.frombuffer(buf, dtype=numpy.uint8)

    if zero:
        labels[labels != 0] = -1
        labels[labels == 0 ] = 1

    if one_hot:
        return dense_to_one_hot(labels, num_classes)
    return labels
```

My modification is adding the **if zero** statement.

However, it says that

```
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you try converting it? `labels = np.asarray(labels)`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I just tried, and there's no bug reported. This makes me even more confused about the **read only** statement

Comment: Meaning that it works?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, it works for `labels = np.asarray(labels)`, however, it will output  `File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py", line 102, in extract_labels
    labels[labels != 0] = -1`
`ValueError: assignment destination` is read-only for my code.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554660/np-arrays-being-immutable-assignment-destination-is-read-only helps.

Comment: Seems like temporarily setting the writable flag is a cleaner option. It will make for less chances of unexpected behavior down the line.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thx, it worked! Now there is another issue: my code `labels[labels != 0] = -1` now makes those labels that not equal to 0 become  255 now. How can I make them to be -1?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, it worked well. Thx1

Comment: @HaiwenHuang try: `dtype=numpy.int8` (not unsigned)