# How to randomize image pixels in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am new to computational vision and python and I could not really figure out what went wrong. I have tried to randomize all the image pixels in a RGB image, but my image turned out to be completely wrong as seen below. Can someone please shed some light?

```
from scipy import misc

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Loads an arbitrary RGB image from the misc library
rgbImg = misc.face()     

%matplotlib inline

#Display out the original RGB image 
plt.figure(1,figsize = (6, 4))
plt.imshow(rgbImg)
plt.show()

#Initialise a new array of zeros with the same shape as the selected RGB image 
rdmImg = np.zeros((rgbImg.shape[0], rgbImg.shape[1], rgbImg.shape[2]))
#Convert 2D matrix of RGB image to 1D matrix
oneDImg = np.ravel(rgbImg)

#Randomly shuffle all image pixels
np.random.shuffle(oneDImg)

#Place shuffled pixel values into the new array
i = 0 
for r in range (len(rgbImg)):
    for c in range(len(rgbImg[0])):
        for z in range (0,3):
            rdmImg[r][c][z] = oneDImg[i] 
            i = i + 1

print rdmImg
plt.imshow(rdmImg) 
plt.show()
```

original image
[image]

image of my attempt in randomizing image pixel
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not shuffling the pixels, you are shuffling everything when you use `np.ravel()` and `np.shuffle()` afterwards.

When you shuffle the pixels, you have to make sure that the color, the RGB tuples, stay the same.

```
from scipy import misc

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Loads an arbitrary RGB image from the misc library
rgbImg = misc.face()

#Display out the original RGB image
plt.figure(1,figsize = (6, 4))
plt.imshow(rgbImg)
plt.show()

# doc on shuffle: multi-dimensional arrays are only shuffled along the first axis
# so let's make the image an array of (N,3) instead of (m,n,3)

rndImg2 = np.reshape(rgbImg, (rgbImg.shape[0] * rgbImg.shape[1], rgbImg.shape[2]))
# this like could also be written using -1 in the shape tuple
# this will calculate one dimension automatically
# rndImg2 = np.reshape(rgbImg, (-1, rgbImg.shape[2]))



#now shuffle
np.random.shuffle(rndImg2)

#and reshape to original shape
rdmImg = np.reshape(rndImg2, rgbImg.shape)

plt.imshow(rdmImg)
plt.show()
```

This is the random racoon, notice the colors. There is not red or blue there. Just the original ones, white, grey, green, black.

[image]

There are some other issues with your code I removed:

- Do not use the nested for loops, slow.
- The preallocation with `np.zeros` is not needed (if you ever need it, just pass `rgbImg.shape` as argument, no need to unpack the separate values)

Comment: Thank you for your input! Do you mean I can just use np.zeros(rgbImg.shape)? And would you be kind enough to suggest scenarios on when do I need to use np.zeros?

Comment: Yes, you can use `np.zeros(rgbImg.shape)`, but there is an even more convenient way: `np.zeros_like(rgbImg)`. Your general idea was fine, `np.zeros` is often used to preallocate an array and fill it afterwards. But usually you are not adding single elements one by one. You could have some for-loop and insert whole rows or columns.

Comment: hi, I copied exactly this code but it only shows me the original racoon pic. It gives me the error `ValueError: assignment destination is read-only`... I use python2.

Comment: About ValueError: assignment destination is read-only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54308748/7919597

Answer (score 1):

Change `plt.imshow(rdmImg)`  into `plt.imshow(rdmImg.astype(np.uint8))`
This may related to this issue https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9391/

Comment: Your original code should print this message in your python console `Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).`. Google it , and you will find the answer for is problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have tried to add in the line as you suggested, and the image does change, however, I might have the issue in the shuffling of pixels as the image does not turn out to contain only the colours of the original image.