# How to map element in pytorch tensor to id?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Given a tensor:

```
A = torch.tensor([2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.])
```

Then, give each element in `A` an id:

```
id = torch.arange(A.shape[0], dtype = torch.int)   # tensor([0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

In other words, id of `2.` in `A` is 0 and  id of `3.` in `A` is 1:

```
2. -> 0
3. -> 1
4. -> 2
5. -> 3
6. -> 4
7. -> 5
```

Then, I have a new tensor:

```
B = torch.tensor([3., 6., 6., 5., 4., 4., 4.])
```

In pytorch, is there any way in Pytorch to map each element in B to id?
In other words, I want to obtain `tensor([1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2])`, in which each element is id of the element in `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a function in PyTorch to map a tensor.

It seems quite unreasonable to solve this by comparing each value from `B` to values from `B`.

Here are two possible solutions to solve this problem.

---

#### Using a dictionary as a map

You can use a *dictionary*. Not so not much of a *pure-PyTorch* solution but will most probably be the fastest and safest way...

Just create a *dict* to map each element to an id, then use it to map *B*:

```
>>> map = {x.item(): i for i, x in enumerate(A)}

>>> torch.tensor([map[x.item()] for x in B])
tensor([1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2])
```

---

#### Change of basis approach

An alternative only using `torch.Tensor`s. This will require the values you want to map - the content of `A` - to be integers because they will be used to index a tensor.

1. Encode the content of `A` into one-hot encodings:

   ```
   >>> A_enc = torch.zeros((int(A.max())+1,)*2)
   >>> A_enc[A, torch.arange(A.shape[0])] = 1

   >>> A_enc
   tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
   ```
2. We'll use `A_enc` as our basis to map integers:

   ```
   >>> v = torch.argmax(A_enc, dim=0)
   tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
   ```
3. Now, given an integer for instance `x=3`, we can encode it into a one-hot-encoding: `x_enc = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Then, use `v` to map it. With a simple dot product you can get the mapping of `x_enc`: here `<v/x_enc>` gives `1` which is the desired result (first element of mapped-`B`). But instead of giving `x_enc`, we will compute the matrix multiplication between `v` and encoded-`B`. First encode `B` then compute the matrix multiplcition `v`x`B_enc`:

   ```
   >>> B_enc = torch.zeros(A_enc.shape[0], B.shape[0])
   >>> B_enc[B, torch.arange(B.shape[0])] = 1

   >>> B_enc
   tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
           [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

   >>> v@B_enc.long()
   tensor([1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2])
   ```

*Note* - you will have to define your tensors with *Long* type.

Answer (score 4):

What you ask can be done with *slowly* iterating the whole `B` matrix and checking each element of it against all elements of `A` and then retrieving the index of each element:

```
In [*]: for x in B:
    ...:     print(torch.where(x==A)[0][0])
    ...:
    ...:
tensor(1)
tensor(4)
tensor(4)
tensor(3)
tensor(2)
tensor(2)
tensor(2)
```

Here I used `torch.where` to find all the True elements in the matrix `x==A`, where `x` take the value of each element of matrix `B`. This is really slow but it allows you to add some functionality to deal with cases where some elements of `B` do not appear in matrix `A`

The fast and dirty method to get what you want with linear algebra operations is:

```
In [*]: (B.view(-1,1) == A).int().argmax(dim=1)
Out[*]: tensor([1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2])
```

This trick takes advantage of the fact that `argmax` returns the first 'max' index of each vector in `dim=1`.

Big warning here, if the element does not exist in the matrix no error will be raised and the result will silently be `0` for all elements that do not exist in `A`.

```
In [*]: C = torch.tensor([100, 1000, 1, 3, 9999])

In [*]: (C.view(-1,1) == A).int().argmax(dim=1)
Out[*]: tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar issue [for numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572448) so my answer is heavily inspired by their solution. I will compare some of the mentioned methods using `perfplot`. I will also generalize the problem to apply a mapping to a tensor (yours is just a specific case).

For the analysis, I will assume the mapping contains all the unique elements in the tensor and the number of elements to small and constant.

```
import torch


def apply(a: torch.Tensor, ids: torch.Tensor, b: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    mapping = {k.item(): v.item() for k, v in zip(a, ids)}
    return b.clone().apply_(lambda x: mapping.__getitem__(x))


def bucketize(a: torch.Tensor, ids: torch.Tensor, b: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    mapping = {k.item(): v.item() for k, v in zip(a, ids)}

    # From `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572448`.
    palette, key = zip(*mapping.items())
    key = torch.tensor(key)
    palette = torch.tensor(palette)

    index = torch.bucketize(b.ravel(), palette)
    remapped = key[index].reshape(b.shape)

    return remapped


def iterate(a: torch.Tensor, ids: torch.Tensor, b: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    mapping = {k.item(): v.item() for k, v in zip(a, ids)}
    return torch.tensor([mapping[x.item()] for x in b])


def argmax(a: torch.Tensor, ids: torch.Tensor, b: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    return (b.view(-1, 1) == a).int().argmax(dim=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import perfplot

    a = torch.arange(2, 8)
    ids = torch.arange(0, 6)

    perfplot.show(
        setup=lambda n: torch.randint(2, 8, (n,)),
        kernels=[
            lambda x: apply(a, ids, x),
            lambda x: bucketize(a, ids, x),
            lambda x: iterate(a, ids, x),
            lambda x: argmax(a, ids, x),
        ],
        labels=["apply", "bucketize", "iterate", "argmax"],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
        xlabel="len(a)",
    )
```

Running this yields the following plot:
[image: Speed against array size]

Hence depending on the number of elements in your tensor you can pick either the `argmax` method (with the caveats mentioned and the restriction that you have to map the values from `0 to N`), `apply`, or `bucketize`.

Now if we increase the number of elements to be mapped lets say tens of thousands i.e. `a = torch.arange(2, 10002)` and `ids = torch.arange(0, 10000)` we get the following results:

[image: Speed against array size with more elements in mapping]

This means the speed increase of `bucketize` will only be visible for a larger array but still outperforms the other methods (the `argmax` method was killed and therefore I had to remove it).

Last, if we have a mapping that does not have all keys present in the tensor we can just update a dictionary with all unique keys:

```
mapping = {x.item(): x.item() for x in torch.unique(a)}
mapping.update({k.item(): v.item() for k, v in zip(a, ids)})
```

Now, if the unique elements you want to map is orders of magnitude larger than the array computing this may shift the value of `n` for when `bucketize` is faster than `apply` (since for apply you can change the `mapping.__getitem__(x)` for `mapping.get(x, x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is an easier way. Create an array as mapper, cast your tensor back into `np.ndarray` first and then address it.

```
import numpy as np
a_array = A.numpy().astype(int)
b_array = B.numpy().astype(int)
mapper = np.zeros(10)
for i, x in enumerate(a_array):
  mapper[x] = i
out = torch.Tensor(mapper[b_array])
```